# Is there an Eslint rule to not let a condition and the conditional body have the same indentation?

Tags: javascript, eslint

What I mean is disallowing this:

```
if (someCondition
  && anotherCondition) {
  doSomething();
}
```

But these are fine:

```
if (someCondition && anotherCondition) {
  doSomething();
}

if (
  someCondition
  && anotherCondition
) {
  doSomething();
}

if (someCondition
  && anotherCondition
) {
  doSomething();
}
```

I want to disallow the first one because it's harder to tell where the conditional body begins.